# Azure Functions and Submodules

Tags: git, azure, azure-functions

So, let's say I have one Azure Function with each function being its own submodule of a repo.

So far, my `.gitmodules` looks like this:

`[submodule "project1"]
    path = project1
    url = git@gitlab.danj.net:app/project1.git`

My `Application Settings`:

`SCM_REPOSITORY_PATH: ..\repository
SCM_TARGET_PATH: ..\..\site\wwwroot`

My deploy keys on my self-hosted GitLab instance have the SSH key from the `api/sshkey?ensurePublicKey=1` endpoint. OK, all good to go, right?

The GitLab repo says its cloned but when I visit the Azure Functions, I get nothing listed. I should have a PowerShell and JavaScript function.

**Site:** https://testcenter123.scm.azurewebsites.net

**One thing to note:** On this self-hosted GitLab instance, I have the projects under a group namespace (like orgs for GitHub). So instead of `git@gitlab.mysite.com:user_1/repo.git`, it is `git@gitlab.mysite.com:a_group/repo.git`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See if this helps: http://blogs.suwatbodin.com/2013/07/deploy-to-windows-azure-using-git-with.html

Comment: @DavidEbbo Hey, I tried it. Using GitLab self-hosted, I was not able to get it to work. I have the id_rsa.pub from Kudu as my SSH key and tried cloning but still got 401... so sadly, it did not work. >_<

Comment: Did you try directly cloning the subrepo from Kudu console to isolate?

Comment: Hi @DavidEbbo Yes, this is what I get:

```PS D:\home\site\wwwroot> git clone git@gitlab.danj.net:app/project1.git
Cloning into 'project1'...
GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Window title cannot be longer than 1023 characters.
```

Which is strange because I have added the the SSH key from KUDU onto GitLab's `project1` Deploy Keys...

Comment: Can you share your web app name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? This will help us investigate. Thanks.

Comment: Hi David, That's fine. You can check it out here `sw-test.azurewebsites.net`. Project names are a bit different than what I posted in the SO question.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm looking at here. I see an empty .ssh folder at the root, as well as a `d:\home\repository` folder that is not actually a git repo.

Comment: Hi @DavidEbbo I updated it a new project with example subrepos with more easier to follow code here: https://testcenter123.scm.azurewebsites.net The new problem being that the azure functions are not being seen. Maybe it's because of the SCM_TARGET_PATH?

Comment: I think I may have forgotten the `function.json` with the actual config info.... @DavidEbbo I think we're fine for now. Thank you so much for your patience.

Comment: glad you got it working!